# Android can´t see the Internal Storage

Tags: adb, 6.0-marshmallow, internal-storage, storage, shell

My Android tells me I don´t have anything on my Internal Storage, but adb shell says I have a file on my Internal Storage (/storage/emulated/0) for example an apk file. Furthermore I haven´t any access to look to the Internal Storage from my android device and computer. What can I do? I have root permissions with adb shell. Could I do something with adb.

Comment: Have you checked that the device isn't in "Only Charging" mode when connected via USB to your computer?  If you swipe down the notification area while your device is connected, you should have options like "Charging Only", or "MTP Access" (could be called "USB Access", every manufacturer labels this slightly differently).